# Firebase security rules: write access on any node with a specific child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

With the following DB structure:

```
Root
  - NodeA
       o    childNodea1
       o    childNodea2
       o    "MyFlag"
  - NodeB
       o    childNodeb1 etc…
  - NodeC
        o   …
  - NodeD etc….
```

I would like to allow write access on any Node only if the child written is "MyFlag". Which means for i.e.:
I don't have write access to `root/NodeA/childNodea1`, but I can write the child `root/NodeA/MyFlag`; either as the child `root/NodeD/MyFlag`

I could write a rule under each Node like this:

```
"NodeA": {
    "MyFlag":{".write": "auth != null"}
 },

(same for eadh other nodes B, C, D ...)
```

But I would like to write something with a wildcard like:

```
"$nodeName": {
      "MyFlag": {".read":true,
                 ".write": "auth != null"}
},
```

This last rule doesn't work (tested on the console simulator).
I also tried:

```
".write": "auth != null && newData.parent().child(MyFlag).exists()",
```

Which doesn't work too.

 Any idea?

Comment: Can you share minimal code snippets for: a write operation that should fail *and* a write operation that should succeed?

Comment: As I explained the test can be done from the console simulator :write on NodeA/childNodea1 (any key/value child) should fail. but write on NodeA/MyFlag should succeed. (same for any other parent Node A, B C ,D)

Comment: to be clearer I want to be able to write the node named "MyFlag" everywhere in the database structure even if I don't have write access on other child nodes